# what does it mean to take strongly to something

Tags: phrases

> Christian literary culture **took strongly to** this form of intellectual labor; at centers of book production like Caesarea, the chapter was both an intellectual tool and a style.

does this mean Christian literary culture was influenced heavily by it?

and in this context

> He had never really **taken strongly to** either Kevin or Kirsty and I didn't like to push the subject.

does that mean he was not fond of either Kevin or Kirsty?

lastly I would like to know if this is correct usage:

"she had not taken strongly to the idea of ..."

meaning she was not fond of this idea

Comment: *to take **strongly** to [an idea / option / person]* isn't very idiomatic. Common qualifiers / intensifiers for the context are [***kindly, readily, quickly, naturally, well, eagerly,...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+*+to+the+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but [there's only one solitary instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22took+strongly+to+the+idea%22) in the entire Google Books corpus of *took **strongly** to the idea*. For the negated version it's almost always ***did not take kindly to** [thing not approved of]*.

Comment: ...also because of the "diminishing" negated qualifier in *had **never really** taken [to people not particularly liked]*, it's a bit odd to also include a non-negated "intensifying" qualifier such as ***strongly, readily, eagerly***. Consider #1 *I never really **liked** anchovies on pizza* (natural) and #2 *I never really **loved** anchovies on pizza* (weird) - where ***loved*** is effectively the "intensified" version of ***liked***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20to):

> take to
> **4 :** to start to have a liking for
> *// I took to her immediately.
>
> // He tried skiing and took to it quickly. [=he quickly learned how to ski and liked doing it]*

To take *strongly* to something means to start liking something a lot and to quickly start doing it.

So to all your questions, the answer is "yes". Christian literary culture was influenced heavily by it, he was not fond of either Kevin or Kirsty, and "*she had not taken strongly to the idea of ...*" is correct usage.

It's worth noting about your first question that this is an indirect meaning. The direct meaning is that Christians involved in literature liked it a lot and quickly started doing it, which implies that Christian literary culture was influenced heavily by it.

Answer (score 2):

To 'take to' someone or something is to start to like that person or thing. 'Strongly' adds that the liking is powerful or great.

> **take to someone/something**
>
> phrasal verb with take verb
>
> to start to like someone or something:
>
> The two dogs took to each other immediately and started to play.
>
> She's taken to basketball like a duck to water (= she likes it and is
> good at it).

[Take to (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-to)